# jQuery add multiple rows, but also have start and end datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have scoured this site and found bits and pieces of code so I can dynamically add a row of data (clone) using jQuery. I have that part working. I also found a way to have a datepicker cloned and it worked. But, the problem I can't solve is how to have a start date AND end date and have multiple rows of them.

Here is a portion of my code:

```
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr').clone(true);
    $tr.find('input.AddRow').val("Delete row");
    var $input = $tr.find('input.startdatum');
    var index = $('input#counter').val();
    var id = 'datepicker' + index;
    index++;
    $('input#counter').val(index);
    $input.attr('id', id).data('index', index);
    console.log(index);
```

//I added this

```
    var $input1 = $tr.find('input.enddatum');
    $input1.attr('id', id).data('index', index);
```

//end

```
    $(this).closest('table').append($tr);
    $('.startdatum').each(function() {
        $(this).datepicker('destroy');
        $(this).datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy'
        });

    });
```

And in the HTML I have:

```
   <input id="datePicker" name="startdatum[]" type="text" class="startdatum"  />
```

I want to add

```
   <input id="datePicker" name="enddatum[]" type="text" class="enddatum"  />
```

I know it has something do to with the INDEX. When I clone the row, I can get back START dates working, but when I try to put an end date in the cloned (2nd) row, it populates the end date of the first row.

What am I missing? Thanks in advance,

Comment: The id's must be unique. Check with that first.

Comment: I get that and that is the problem. my 2nd end date isn't having the ID# added to the end, so it matches the first end date. I am not sure where in the code I need to change it to update the 2nd end date.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured it out. 
My partial code now:

```
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr').clone(true);
    $tr.find('input.AddRow').val("Delete row");
    var $input = $tr.find('input.startdatum');
    var index = $('input#counter').val();
    var id = 'startdate' + index;
    var $input1 = $tr.find('input.enddatum');
    var index1 = $('input1#counter').val();
    var id1 = 'enddate' + index;
    index++;
    $('input#counter').val(index);
    $('input1#counter').val(index1);

    $input.attr('id', id).data('index', index);
    $input1.attr('id', id1).data('index', index);
    console.log(index);
```

And in the html:

```
  <input id="startdate[]" name="startdatum[]" type="text" class="startdatum" /> - 
  <input id="enddate[]" name="enddatum[]" type="text" class="enddatum"  />
```

Comment: Good... I was just writing an answer like this. ^_^

Comment: Ok, so now I figured out something more I want. I want a TEXT AREA but it needs to be un a new TR, with colspan across the other row. But, with how I have it now, it won't clone the 2nd TR. Any ideas?

Comment: Ignore me. I have been working on this too long. I used CSS include the main TD to accomplish what I wanted. DUH!